# Which is the equivalent of Job(Kotlinx Coroutines) in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, kotlin, swiftui, kotlin-coroutines

I'm developing in SwiftUI for iOS.
I would like to know the equivalent of Job (Kotlinx Coroutines) in Swift?

for example in Kotlin when we need to execute certain processes upon the finalisation of other process we would do something like this:

```kotlin
        //You can select between different dispatchers
        val job: Job = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            executeProcess1()
            executeProcess2()
        }
        // .join() means it will wait on that line until that job is completed.
        job.join()
        
        // we could also use .invokeOnCompletion to execute a process on completion of the job.
        job.invokeOnCompletion {
            executeProcess3()
        }
```

Is "Task" the equivalent? I see Task is used more in the "View" layer, meaning directly in the SwiftUI code, or it can also be used in the ViewModel?
I would like to avoid Combine, if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Does this medium post give you any pointers](https://medium.com/futuremind/handling-kotlin-multiplatform-coroutines-in-swift-koru-4a80b93f232b)?.

Comment: thanks, I see they implement Combine... I would like to avoid Combine if possible and use it as a last resource. @MartinMarconcini

Comment: Have a read of the Swift concurrency guide https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/concurrency/ It should make it a bit clearer as to how concurrency works in Swift and what the equivalent of what you are trying to do is.

Comment: Check for DispatchGroup, DispatchSemaphore or Async Await in Swift.

Comment: Semaphores are the closet thing but I would want "Meet async/await" it is a much safer approach

Comment: A DispatchGroup is probably the closest GCD construct, or use async/await with a [TaskGroup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/taskgroup)

Comment: Thanks for the info, reading the documentation cleared me out many doubts. I believe GroupTask, Task and async let are the closest thing to Jobs in Kotlin, they look cool also. :) @JeremyP